# Is it possible to export sql file on node js using html button?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sqlite

Im new into programming, Is it possible to export sql file on node js using SQLite? For example, I want a button that instantly exports .sql file from my database. 
I am using Node JS with SQLite, using DB browser application,

for manual exporting, i need to go to DB browser app then file>>export>>Database to sql format

but i want it on html button, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's two pieces to this:

**1. The HTML button triggering an AJAX call to the Node Server**

Take a quick look at [HapiJS Server](https://hapijs.com/) and run through their quick start to understand how to receive a request.

**2. The Node Server generating the .sql file.**

There is [an NPM package for sqlite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) that has a run command. Use that to create a dump file just like you would from the sqlite CLI.

```
// In the CLI
# sqlite3 yourDatabase.db '.dump' > backup.dump

// In node
db.run("'.dump' > backup.dump");
```

From there, you can return the file as your response. Use node's [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) to read the generated .dump file.

Comment: i tried it, but it prints buffer with hex characters?